# I'm not able to get the Key attribute value from the JSON file using jq in shell

Tags: json, shell, unix, jq

I'm trying to get the Key from the below JSON file:

I just executed the below command which will give the below JSON output

**Command:**

```
jq -r '.issues'
```

**Output:**

```
 {
    "expand": "schema,names",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 50,
    "total": 4,
    "issues": [{
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "1999875",
            "self": "https://amazon.kindle.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/1999875",
            "key": "KINDLEAMZ-67578"
        },
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "2019428",
            "self": "https://amazon.kindle.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/2019428",
            "key": "KINDLEAMZ-68661"
        },
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "2010958",
            "self": "https://amazon.kindle.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/2010958",
            "key": "KINDLEAMZ-68167"
        }
    ]
}
```

I just want to get the output as below format and not sure how to get it.

https://jqplay.org/s/0IfiBoskG5

**Expected Output:**

```
{
"JIRA-1":"KINDLEAMZ-67578",

"JIRA-2":"KINDLEAMZ-68661",

"JIRA-3":"KINDLEAMZ-68167"
}
```

How can I get key value from each of the array and display like above? and JIRA-n will be increase based on the result.

When I run this command in shell but getting this error. And It works in the filter not in shell.

**Command:**

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jq

readFile=$(cat response.json)

echo "$readFile"  // It contains the above JSON file that mentioned as output

getResponse=$($readFile | reduce (.issues | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({}; .["JIRA-\($key + 1)"] = $value.key ))

echo "$getResponse"
```

**Error:**
/tmp/jenkins5142826499545309380.sh: command substitution: line 46: syntax error near unexpected token `.issues'
/tmp/jenkins5142826499545309380.sh: command substitution: line 46:`$readFile | reduce (.issues | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({}; .["JIRA-($key + 1)"] = $value.key ))'

This is not duplicate, can you please remove it as duplicate and help me to get answer?

Comment: To start with, your JSON is not even valid for `jq` to parse it. You are missing the array start `[` at line 6. With the JSON fixed, your attempt `reduce (.issues | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({};     .["JIRA-\($key + 1)"] = $value.key )` should work as expected

Comment: Updated the question with valid json. Sorry its typo

Comment: Your filter works as expected now and produces the output needed

Comment: Yes working fine... It might be json parse issue.

Comment: @inian, @ oguz ismail, - Can you please check the updated question, and Its not duplicate. Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Modify your command to `getResponse=$( jq 'reduce (.issues | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({}; .["JIRA-\($key + 1)"] = $value.key )' response.json ); echo "$getResponse"`. You don't need to `cat` contents to `readFile=$(cat response.json)`

Comment: Let me check and update you.

Comment: error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '$'
reduce (.issues | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({}; .["JIRA-\($key + 1)"] = $value.key )
                                   ^
1 compile error

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the posted JSON, the following gives the desired result:

```
.issues
| with_entries( .key |= "JIRA-\(. + 1)" | .value |= .key )
```

Notice that there is no need to use `reduce`.